# MEF ImportDefinitions are not null, but Import attribute doesn't work

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, mef

I'm trying to run my application with MEF infrastructure.

I have next code
[in MainWindow code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsiX.png).
Before I do next configuration with MEF
[Screenshot with CompositionContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k09yn.png)

However property Interface is null. Why it might be null?

Container catalog Parts is not empty. ImportDefinitions for MainWindow is not empty.Import and Export attributes has exactly the same metadata (typeof(IApiClient)).

What I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. Actually there are needed custom Bootstrapper, with overrided method ConfigureAggregateCatalog. From method Application_Startup custom bootstrapper should be created and ran.